# Suricata conditional alerts

Tags: suricata

I'm asking about **Suricata**

Is there way to write a conditional alert?

For example - alert of HTTP GET if the  server status to the request is "success"

Thanks,
Efrat

Answer (score 0):

All alerts are conditional as they are triggered by the conditions in a rule.

A rule to match on the status message in http would be something like:

> alert http any any -> any any (content:"success"; http_stat_msg; sid:12345;)

See https://redmine.openinfosecfoundation.org/projects/suricata/wiki/HTTP-keywords#http_stat_msg

Answer (score 0):

You can do that provided you update your rule file name  in suricata.yaml file. Easiest way to do is to do is :

1. Create custom.rule file with custom alerts
2. add customer.rule into the list of rules.
3. do a live reload ( Kill -USR2 )or

   ```
   start :suricata -c /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml -i <interface>
   ```
4. when you send traffic you must be able see alerts in fast.log